Aeron ConcurrentPublication vs ExclusivePublication. Is this managing concurrency at the Object level, or at the LogBuffer level?
In Java Aeron, at the Object level, I understand that if I have multiple threads writing to a single Publication instance, it had better be a ConcurrentPublication. But what if each thread has its own ExclusivePublication instance, with all Publications writing to the same channel/streamId? Is that safe?
Taking it further, if I have N threads in N different JVM's, all writing to the same channel and streamId, there is of course no need or possibility of managing concurrent access at the Object level. This leads me to suspect/hope that you can have many ExclusivePublication instances on the same channel/streamId, and that the 'Exclusive' prefix is limited in scope to just the Object level.
